# Contour plot with x, y and z values?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, map, infinite-loop

I have x , y and z as

```
x = List[1.355, 1.357, 1.359, 1.36, 1.357, 1.355];
```

and

```
y = List[-1.22, -1.22, -1.22, -1.23, -1.23, -1.23];
```

and

```
z = List[416.39, 415.21, 414.22, 413.54, 413.25, 413.21];
```

and plot the following,

```
ListContourPlot[{{1.355, -1.22, 416.39}, {1.357, -1.22, 415.21}, {1.359, -1.22, 414.22}, 
{1.36, -1.23, 413.54}, {1.357, -1.23, 413.25}, {1.355, -1.23, 413.21}}]
```

but I don't want to put the values in ListContourPlot manually, is there any way, I can call the values in listcontourplot automatically, please do consider that I have almost 500's of x, y and z values and there is no sequence in those values.

Comment: `Transpose[{x,y,z}]`

Answer (score 2):

With your  definitions of `x,y,z` try

```
xyz=Transpose[{x,y,z}]; 
ListContourPlot[data]
```